# How to use blazorise TimeEdit in 24h format

Tags: c#, blazorise

I know how to use Blazorise time edit component, but the problem is that I don't know how to use it in 24h format.
I will appreciate it if you send me a guide or introduce any other component which I can use instead in my Blazorise project.
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "don't know how to use it in 24h"? You put it on the page and then pick a time with it. It shows 24h, no? - https://bootstrapdemo.blazorise.com/tests/forms

Comment: @CaiusJard I mean how to use it without AM/PM format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimeEdit component is based on `input type="time"`, meaning it will be controlled by the browser so it is not possible to change the display or edit format. Instead you can use Blazorise new component, named TimePicker that has the ability to change format.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that